# Ordering Select clause result in specific way

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need  help with writing a **select** clause query.

For example, lets say I have a query like that:

```
select value from some_table order by value asc;
```

as a result I get this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

but a special query I want to write, is the one which still will give me *sorted* values, but will put *5* after *8*.

this means I need one value to be out of *regular* order.

it can be described in other way. lets say I have two groups of numbers (example):
A={ a | 1<=a<=118, a!=78 } B={ b | b>118 }
I have a group C=A U B U {78}
and I need all these values sorted like "A,78,B"

Comment: In your final example, what if value is not in any of the three groups? I.e. negative numbers and zero.

Comment: SQL has but one data structure: the table. Model your groups as rows and columns in a table including a `sort_order` column. `JOIN` to this table in your query and use the `sort_order` column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming value is integer, you could do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
ORDER BY
       CASE
         WHEN value = 5 THEN 8.5
         ELSE value
       END
```

Comment: Note: This might put 5 after 9 as well.

Comment: I don't like this but it seems popular so I'll play along... why not use `WHEN value = 5 THEN 8.5` instead?

Comment: @Mark Byers - Yes, that's definitely better. I don't know why I did 3 case statements. I think I'm nervous about the upcoming topcoder SRM and not thinking as clearly as I should :).

Comment: thank you "order by case when cat_list=78 then 118.5 else cat_list end asc"

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple conditions in your order by:

```
ORDER BY (value BETWEEN 1 AND 118) AND value != 78 DESC,
         value > 118 DESC,
         value
```

This will ensure that values which match the first predicate come first, then values matching the second predicate, and finally values matching none of the predicates. If there is a tie (two numbers matching the same predicate) then these numbers are sorted in ascending order.

Note that I haven't tested this in Oracle. It might be necessary to wrap the predicate in a CASE expression `(CASE WHEN predicate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` to get the sorting to work in Oracle.

```
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN ((value BETWEEN 1 AND 118) AND value <> 78) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
    (CASE WHEN (value > 118) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
    value
```

Comment: I don't think that works on Oracle. When I tried it, I get "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", and it's complaining about the first space after the first "value".

Comment: Hmm... after the fix to make it work in Oracle I prefer DRapp's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or to expand upon DCP's answer...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl 
ORDER BY 
       CASE 
         WHEN (Condition for first grouping) THEN 1
         WHEN (Condition for second grouping) THEN 2
         WHEN (Condition for third grouping) THEN 3
         ELSE 4
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by some [CASE-expression](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/pl_sql/htdocs/x/Case/start.htm) to remap your values.